# What does Takeout and Putup mean?

Tags: trading, bonds, terminology, fixed-income

[image]What does takeout and putup values mean in fixed income trade and how would you interpret these values?

Comment: Can you provide the context? I've heard takeout used a few different ways but have never heard of "putup"

Comment: I imagine putup is the opposite/the other side of a trade.

Well, buying one bond and selling the other bond is the context I am referring to.

Comment: It is helpful to include the full context of the quote.  Presumably, you're looking at a statement from some resource that is using both of these terms.  It's helpful to say "I was reading Bond Investing for Fun and Profit by John Doe.  On page 16 he writes "I putup with a lot of grief for fouling up the takeout order..."" because there may be some context there.

Comment: Acctually, it's from a bloomberg screen shot of a trade ticket and don't think I can post that on here.

Comment: pasted the bloomberg snippet

Comment: @the_brass_bottle you missed the FV out of your question which is the entire context it is actually takeout FV and put up FV you want to know about which actually makes sense

Comment: @MD-Tech There is a Takeout/Putup heading without FV just above "Horizon Date"

Comment: Okay. thanks all, so really its kind of not a useful stat to determine value its just telling you what's raised or spent on the trade.

Answer (score 1):

Bloomberg usually has pretty good help and may define those terms in its online help.

My *guess* based on the screenshot you show is:

The takeout/putup number is the difference in NPV (how much you would get/have to pay at settlement) between the two bonds. If you buy $1,000 notional of one of these bonds and sell the same amount of the other, you will "take out" $16,037 (or vice verse, you would have to "put up" an additional $16,037 to buy the more expensive one).

Note that it doesn't directly say anything about the quality of those bonds (a cheaper bond is not always "better") just shows the difference needed to settle the trade.

I have never seen these terms used in an analytic context - they may be specific to Bloomberg or a trading term. But the main thing to notice is that it is the difference in NPV between the two bonds.